# Remove price decimals on list and product view

Tags: price, catalog-price-rules

I want to remove the decimals of our price only on the list and product view.
For example I want to change the price from $14,00 to $14,-

In the checkout, e-mails and PDF I want to keep the decimals for the tax.

How can I easily fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only on those specific places the easiest (not the prettiest) way to do it with a replace in the `price.phtml`.

```
$price = ...;
$price = str_replace(',00', ',-', $price);
```

Another option would be to have a custom extension that rewrites the `formatPrice` method but since it's only visual that might be overkill.

So in `price.html` replace

```
<?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price, true) ?>
```

with

```
<?php $_price = str_replace(',00', ',-', $_price); ?>
<?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price, true) ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that! But I really do not know exactly what line I need to modify into what exactly. Because everything I tried in price.phtml did not work.

Comment: If you replaced all of them it might not be the right PHTML file. Please use template hints to check which file it is

Comment: I did used the correct file. But there is non line that I can easily replace with `$price = str_replace(',00', ',-', $price); ` What exact line do I need to replace in this file? I do see this line: `<?php $_price = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_convertedPrice); ?>`

Comment: every place where an echo is done parse what ever is echoed through the str_replace

Comment: I don not quite get it. Can you give an example of a line?

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for the update. I replaced the correct line with you code, but that did not work. Nothing happend

Comment: It can be several different lines. First make sure that phtml file is used and then which line it is. Also make sure the comma is not a dot

Comment: I tried several lines, that use the same code with $_price and I also tried to replace the comma for a dot, but that also does not seem to work. I placed your code exactly above the line with $_price.

Comment: When I change your code, it does brake down the price. So it should be effecting the price, but it does not work.

Comment: Do you know a possible problem, why your code does not work?